# definite integration with monte Carlo does not have the acceptable error

Tags: c++, montecarlo

I wish to calculate the integration of `e^(- landa x) cosx` from zero to positive infinity. The exact solution is `landa/((landa^2)+1)`. The example I'm trying to solve forces me to have a maximum error of 0.01.
Here, the approach I am taking is that I first generate a random number from uniform distribution function `[0,1]` and then transform it via `(-1/landa ln (x))` so, each variable will now have the probability of `(landa * e ^(-landa x))`. The thing which I do not understand is that when I am increasing N from 1 million to be 100 million, the error changes in the following manner, which of course does not fulfill the criteria of the problem, and the weird thing is that from N of `1000000` to N of `10000000`, the error is increasing.
The error versus N is :

```
N=1000000    0.0997496
N=100000000  0.0999462
N=100000000  0.0999341
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
double landa = 1;
double function(double x) {
    return (exp(-landa * x) * cos(x));
}

int main()
{
    unsigned seed = 0;
    srand(seed);
    double exact_solution = landa / (pow(landa, 2) + 1);
    const int N = 100000000;
    default_random_engine g(seed);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0f, nextafter(1.0f, DBL_MAX));
    double sum = 0.0;
    double app;
    double error;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    double x = distribution(g);
    // transform xs 
    x = (-1.0 / landa) * log(x);
    sum = sum + function(x);
    }

    app = sum / static_cast<double> (N);
    error = exact_solution - app;
    cout << N << "\t" << error << endl; 

}
```

Comment: first, if you are dealing with random number and you want to compare different runs you should keep the seed fixed

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi the seed is fixed here to be zero

Comment: my bad, I missed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Damien wrote is good wrt the fact that you have to remove exponent part from function, you already using it for sampling.

Where he is wrong, is the fact that you have to remove whole NORMALIZED exponential PDF

PDF(x|λ) = λ*exp(-λ x),

which means that integrated function shall pick up λ in the denominator. In other words, code with cos(x) will only work for λ=1

f(x) = λ*exp(-λ x) * cos(x)/λ

In the expression above first part is PDF used for sampling, and second part is what you're trying to compute mean value.

This is fixed code, tested on Win10 x64, LLVM 11.0.1

```
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double lambda = 1.5;

inline double function(double x) {
    return cos(x) / lambda;
}

int main() {

    double exact_solution = lambda / (lambda*lambda + 1.0);

    const int N = 100000000;

    std::mt19937_64 g(12345671LL);

    uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution{}; // a bit raster with range [0...1)

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        double x = distribution(g);
        x = (-1.0 / lambda) * log(1.0 - x); // to avoid domain error
        sum += function(x);
    }

    double app   = sum / static_cast<double> (N);
    double error = exact_solution - app;
    cout << N << "\t" << error << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Effectively, you are right, I was fast a little bit in checking the result. I corrected my answer thanks to you.

Comment: Is there any reason that you are using `td::mt19937_64 ` instead of default generation?

Comment: @MAero2020 It is best quality generator available in the standard C++ library.  For demos and tests default generator is ok, I guess, but I used to use 64bit version of MT.

Answer (score 1):

You made a confusion: once you have generated `x` with the proper distribution, then you have to integrate `cos(x)` simply.

```
    sum = sum + cos(x);
```

Output:

```
1000000         -0.0010428
10000000        0.000105266
100000000       -2.08618e-05
```

---

**Correction**

As @Severin Pappadeux correctly mentioned in a comment, and in their answer, I was fast a little bit in checking a result and forgot a normalisation factor `1/landa`. It has no incidence for `landa = 1` of course.

There are different ways to explain this factor.

One way is the following: if you make the variable change `u = exp(-landa*x)`, then you get

```
dx = -1/(landa*u) du
```

This `landa` factor in the denominator is missing in the final integration sum...

Comment: here f(x) is cos(x) e^(-land x) not cos(x) . also, the output of this code is not acceptable since by increasing N, the absolute error has been increased

Comment: I know. But in the original integration, `x` follow an uniform low. After the transformation `y = g(x)`, the integral becomes `integral of cos(y)`

Comment: Yeah, I see my mistake, Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is NOT correct. You have to have normalization in the function. Please check my answer

Comment: @Severin I just checked that I get the same result as OP theoretical result. I did not check this result, I assumed it was correct. But I don't see your answer...maybe to come...